# Send activation link to unregistered user in Wordpress

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress, contact-form

I have a frontend posting form- I am using Contact Form 7.

The data is saved as a post, which has status "pending".

I want to send user a email, in which there will be activation link to change status from "pending" to "published". THE USER IS NOT REGISTERED! I want to keep it that way.

I searched a lot for the solution, but I only found plugins which sends mail to REGISTERED users.

I found one code online, but it is not complete:

```
$unique = md5( $post->post_content );
add_post_meta( $post->ID, '_auto_publish', $unique );

// link to be sent
$link = get_permalink( $post->ID );
$link = add_query_arg(
array(
    'autopublish' => $unique,
    'pid'         => $post->ID
),
$link
);

if ( isset ( $_GET[ 'autopublish' ] )
and isset ( $_GET[ 'pid' ] )
and is_numeric( $_GET[ 'pid' ] )
and $post = get_post( $_GET[ 'pid' ] )
and $_GET[ 'autopublish' ] === get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_auto_publish', TRUE )
)
{
$post->post_status = 'publish';
wp_update_post( $post );
delete_post_meta( $post->ID, '_auto_publish' );
}
```

This should be implemented as a plugin. You think it could work? I want to test it, but cannot input 
    print $link 
to the CF7 autoresponder mail.

Is there a better solution for that. Remember, the user who submits form is NOT REGISTERED member.

Comment: What you can do is, you can generate one unique random code when user submit the form and store that unique random code in the table with that particular entry. Then generate the URL with that unique random code and send that URL to the users mail box and when user clicks and land on that particular page register him. is as simple as that. You wont get ready made code for this.

Comment: Any more detailed guidance for that? U have a profile on Fiver or similar?

Comment: Please explain the `detail` so according to that definition I will help you.

Comment: Ok, thanks, will get in touch! Need to get to details first :) But its good to know thats possible.

Comment: I created now I custom function, which generates a random string. Included that in the form as a hidden field. What I have now is a link mydomain.com/0jfs0jf2fj09 for example.. Stuck here, how to continue? Should I use the code I published in the question?

Comment: Construct link like this `mydomain.com/validate.php?verify=0jfs0jf2fj09` and send this link to user via email and when user will click on this link validate him. Write your validation code in `validate.php`. use `$_GET` to retrieve the `random string` from url. That's it.

Comment: Will be too hard for me alone to do that. If someone is interested let me know your Fiver account details, I will post the working code here later. Thanks Mengesh for your help!